# vert.x ResponseTimeHandler is not giving correct processing time of the request

Tags: vert.x

We have vert.x server running and we fetch req.response().headers().get("x-response-time");
after request.response().end();

We use the result as response time taken for our api's behind vert.x.
For few of the api requests I have seen x-response-time is more like 25000ms which is very huge.
So I added one more metric to calculate response time on my own, when request enters the verticle its start time and once response is sent its end time.Difference of these two I took as my customRespTime.

Now I compared customRespTime added by me with x-response-time added by vert.x. They both are not matching and vert.x shows huge response time like 25000ms for few of the requests.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug? The best thing would be to prepare a reproducer and submit it to the `vertx-web` repository on GitHub

Comment: Probably in nanoseconds or something is holding up the response headers being written. I am using the response time handler  (for years) and it works as expected